# Tips on writing optimised project in Python with C/C++ extensions?

Tags: python, optimization, project, mpi

I have a project written in IDL (interactive data language) that is used to produce a near real time model of the ionosphere by assimilating a heap of different data inputs. IDL is not a great language for this to be written in, but it is so mainly because of legacy code. The project is written in OO style despite the relatively limited object environment in IDL.

The scope of the next generation of this project is much larger and will require much more computing grunt. IDL has limited support from multi-threading and no support for parallel  running on distributed memory systems. The original plan was to write the next generation code in C++ using MPI to parallelize, however I have recently started learning Python and am very impressed with the ease of use and ability to rapidly develop and maintain code. I am now considering writing the high level parts of this project in Python and using C extensions when/if required to improve the optimisation of the core number crunching parts.

Since I'm new to Python, it won't be immediately obvious to me where Python is likely to be slow compared to a C version (and I'll also probably do things sub-optimally in Python until I learn its idiosyncrasies). This means I'll thinking of basically planning out the whole project as if it was to be done all in Python, write the code, profile and optimise repeatedly until I can't make any more improvements and then look to replace the slowest parts with C extensions.

Is this a good approach? Does anyone have any tips for developing this kind of project? I'll be looking to utilise as many existing well optimised libraries as possible (such as scaLAPACK) which may also reduce the need to roll my own C based extensions for the number crunching.

Comment: Are you aware of [Numpy and Scipy](http://www.scipy.org)? Those offer Matlab-like numerical/vector programming for Python. Number crunching in Python without Numpy is like riding a bike with square wheels. Also, [Cython](http://cython.org) makes writing C extensions much easier. You might not have to write a single line of C; in the scikit-learn project, we implemented several machine learning algorithms in Cython.

Comment: Yes I am aware of Numpy and Scipy, I've installed both but haven't used them yet but certainly intend to. I should have pointed that out in the question. I was not aware of Cython though, that looks very useful for my purposes, thanks.

Comment: I've implemented a reasonably serious piece of software exactly as you describe, using Python with lots of numpy to architect and then dropping to C only when necessary for optimisation. I originally used ctypes, but now I'd use Cython with no hesitation. The big advantage of Cython is that you can write in basically pure python and then incrementally optimise (check out the [cython numpy tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html)). The development model is fantastic though and I strongly advocate it. Take some time to get to grips with Numpy as it is a hugely capable library.

Answer (score 2):

Python is especially slow when you do a lot of looping, especially nested loops

```
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        ....
```

When it comes computationally intensive problems, 99% of the problems can be solved by doing vectorized calculations with numpy instead of looping, e.g.:

```
x = np.arange(1000) #numbers from 0 to 999
y = np.arange(1000, 2000) #numbers from 1000 to 1999

# slow:
for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] += x[i]

# fast:
y += x
```

For many scientific problems there are binary libraries, written in FORTRAN or C(++), that are available in Python. This makes life really easy.

If you come to a point where this is not possible, I'd stick to Cython to easily implement the core parts in C, without writing C.